# wrong positioning in android layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I can't get right positioning in frame layout and I have no idea why is it so.
I need to stick exit_layout(LinearLayout in the end of code snippet) to the upper left corner of the screen.

The XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/exit_layout"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exit_button_mode"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_exit_icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_beck_to_main"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/modes"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_choose_mode"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button_beginner_mode"
                    android:background="@drawable/beginner_button"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button_advanced_mode"
                    android:background="@drawable/advanced_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tv_mode_beginner"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tv_mode_advanced"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button_expert_mode"
                    android:background="@drawable/expert_button"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/button_custom_mode"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tv_mode_expert"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tv_mode_custom"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot of the screen:

[image]

Comment: post your complete layout file. I think something is missing from the end

Comment: Why don't you use linearlayout as parent layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change height and width of your first linear layout to match parent:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/modes">
```

You may need to adjust margins for other views inside this layout to place them at desired location.

Also, frame layout doesn't seem necessary here, you can achieve desired result just by using linear layouts.

---

**Update**

As layout in question is changed modify it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/exit_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exit_button_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/Capture" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="Main Menu"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/modes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose Game Mode"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#aaaaaa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--remove bg color from linear layout-->
            <!--add your buttons in place of textview-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Add your remaining layout here"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

result :

[image]

Comment: but how can i place stuff in layout without specific margin ??

Comment: @VladZbuker which margin ?

Comment: @RahulTiwiari any margin whatsoever. Because positioning on screen will change on different screens and thats is not good.

Comment: I don't think you will need any margin if you use `android:gravity ="center"` in your linear layout.

Comment: @RahulTiwiari edited the code snippet and the question itself but still not getting the right result =(

Comment: you have changed entire layout, solution was for original layout :). Ill get back to you with solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is not having a huge space on the top.
Also try adding this line to your ImageButton:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If it still fails try using an ImageView instead of an ImageButton:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exit_button_mode"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exit_icon"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You XML works absolutely fine as it displays your exit_layout at the top left corner of the screen. I think the problem lies in your assets. Look for them or any sort of margins that might be causing your XML to display such view